# Not able to connect mongodb via redash

Tags: mongodb, terminal, connection, redash

I am trying to connect to mongodb to redash from local machine.

1) Both mongo and redash are on standalone system.
2) I am able to connect to mongo from terminal. Please see the my terminal details after, I login to it.

```
rahul@rahul-VirtualBox:~$ mongo -u rahul -p
MongoDB shell version v3.6.3
Enter password: 
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
MongoDB server version: 3.6.3
Server has startup warnings: 
2019-05-24T20:05:14.788+0530 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] 
2019-05-24T20:05:14.788+0530 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Using the XFS filesystem is strongly recommended with the WiredTiger storage engine
2019-05-24T20:05:14.788+0530 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] **          See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/prodnotes-filesystem
2019-05-24T20:05:16.607+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2019-05-24T20:05:16.607+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
2019-05-24T20:05:16.607+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
2019-05-24T20:05:16.607+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
> show dbs
admin   0.000GB
config  0.000GB
local   0.000GB
>
```

3) I am using Ubuntu 16.04 as my OS.
4) Details i am entering to connect to `Mongo` using `redash`

> Name: Localhost_mongo
>  Connection
>   String:mongodb://rahul:password@127.0.0.1:27017
>  
>   Database Name:admin

5) I am getting error `connection refused err no:111`
6) Below is my config file details & location : /etc/mongodb.conf

```
# mongodb.conf

# Where to store the data.
dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb

#where to log
logpath=/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log

logappend=true

bind_ip = 0.0.0.0
port = 27017

# Enable journaling, http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Journaling
journal=true

# Enables periodic logging of CPU utilization and I/O wait
#cpu = true

# Turn on/off security.  Off is currently the default
#noauth = true
#auth = true

# Verbose logging output.
#verbose = true

# Inspect all client data for validity on receipt (useful for
# developing drivers)
#objcheck = true

# Enable db quota management
#quota = true

# Set diagnostic logging level where n is
#   0=off (default)
#   1=W
#   2=R
#   3=both
#   7=W+some reads
#diaglog = 0

# Diagnostic/debugging option
#nocursors = true

# Ignore query hints
#nohints = true

# Disable the HTTP interface (Defaults to localhost:27018).
#nohttpinterface = true

# Turns off server-side scripting.  This will result in greatly limited
# functionality
#noscripting = true

# Turns off table scans.  Any query that would do a table scan fails.
#notablescan = true

# Disable data file preallocation.
#noprealloc = true

# Specify .ns file size for new databases.
# nssize = <size>

# Accout token for Mongo monitoring server.
#mms-token = <token>

# Server name for Mongo monitoring server.
#mms-name = <server-name>

# Ping interval for Mongo monitoring server.
#mms-interval = <seconds>

# Replication Options
#   3=both
#   7=W+some reads
#diaglog = 0

# Diagnostic/debugging option
#nocursors = true

# Ignore query hints
#nohints = true

# Disable the HTTP interface (Defaults to localhost:27018).
#nohttpinterface = true

# Turns off server-side scripting.  This will result in greatly limited
# functionality
#noscripting = true

# Turns off table scans.  Any query that would do a table scan fails.
#notablescan = true

# Disable data file preallocation.
#noprealloc = true

# Specify .ns file size for new databases.
# nssize = <size>

# Accout token for Mongo monitoring server.
#mms-token = <token>

# Server name for Mongo monitoring server.
#mms-name = <server-name>

# Ping interval for Mongo monitoring server.
#mms-interval = <seconds>

# Replication Options
```

Please help.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please comment out bind-ip in config file, restart mongod service and try again once.

Comment: @PriyankaKariya `bind-ip` was earlier comment. Yet i wasn't able to connect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you [added iptable rules](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/configure-linux-iptables-firewall/) since you have mentioned that redash and mongodb are both on  standalone systems? If you have already done check if you have  a conflict between multiple rules.

I have noticed a user suggesting to comment out **bind_ip** line which you shouldn't do, since `bind_ip = 0.0.0.0` allows connection to be established from all hosts.